# Check if an array of objects exists

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
items: [
  { name: "Cheese Puffs", price: 3 },
  { name: "Can of Soda", price: 1.75 }
];
```

I want to do something like `items["cheesePuffs"] === true`. But as it is in an array it won't work properly.

Comment: is `'yes'` `true`?

Comment: No it's just a value, not necessarily meaning anything.

Comment: You should fix the syntax of the code in your question.  Semicolons don't belong inside of an object literal like that.

Comment: The duplicate given has answers that doesn't necessarily match my requirements.

Comment: not duplicate, according to this question, OP wants to check is there any object in array or not, and marked duplicate question is for, is any key available in object !!

Comment: I dont think these 2 questions are duplicate,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
myArrOfObjects.find(el => el.cheesePuffs);
```

Assuming the property you're looking for is truthy, this returns the element, `{cheesePuffs: "yes"}` which is truthy.  If it weren't found, it would be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `some` and `hasOwnProperty`, If you need actual value instead of Boolean values you can use `find` instead of `some`

```js
const myArrOfObjects = [{
  cheesePuffs: "yes"
},
{
  time: "212"
}];

let findByName = (name) => {
  return myArrOfObjects.some(obj=> {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(name)
  })
}

console.log(findByName("cheesePuffs"))
console.log(findByName("time"))
console.log(findByName("123"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use find

```js
let exist = myArrOfObjects.find(o => o.cheesePuffs === 'yes')
```

Comment: read code of conduct: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct. Use code snippet to write code.

Comment: i.e. use ` and to end it use `

Answer (score 1):

okay simple solutions

try this

```js
const x = [{}];

if(x.find(el => el.cheesePuffs) == undefined)
  console.log("empty objects in array ")
  
const myArrOfObjects = [{
  cheesePuffs: "yes"
},
{
  time: "212"
}];


if(myArrOfObjects.find(el => el.cheesePuffs) == undefined)
  console.log("empty objects in array ")
  else
  console.log("objects available in array ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. It will return you the object where name matches to 'Cheese Puffs'.

```js
let items = [{
    name: "Cheese Puffs",
    price: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Can of Soda",
    price: 1.75
  }
];

let itemExist = items.find(x => x.name === 'Cheese Puffs');

if (itemExist) {
  console.log(itemExist);
} else {
  console.log("Item not Exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggestion, you can also decide to not use an array, but to use a json object, where the index of each item is the unique name of your objects (in the example "cheesePuffs" identifies "Cheese Puffs")

```js
let items = {
"cheesePuffs": {name: "Cheese Puffs",price: 3},
"canOfSoda": {name: "Can of Soda",price: 1.75},
};

console.log("exist: ", items.cheesePuffs!== undefined)
console.log(items.cheesePuffs)
// can also access to item in this way:
console.log(items["cheesePuffs"])

console.log("not exist", items.noCheesePuffs!== undefined)
console.log(items.noCheesePuffs)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have an array of objects so you can't simply use

```
myArrOfObjects["cheesePuffs"]
```

because array required an index so it should be `myArrOfObjects[0]["cheesePuffs"]`

```js
let items = [
  { name: "Cheese Puffs", price: 3 },
  { name: "Can of Soda", price: 1.75 }
];


let filter = items.find( el => el.price === 3 );

console.log(filter);
```

another approach

```js
  let items = [
      { name: "Cheese Puffs", price: 3 },
      { name: "Can of Soda", price: 1.75 }
    ];


    let filter = items.filter( el => el.price === 3 );

    console.log(filter);
```